# How can I replace bold lines before a pattern with a macro in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was asked by a colleague if I could write a word macro to help them out; they use a service that dumps several newspaper articles into one word file without any headings and they'd like to create a TOC.

I said 'Absolutely not' because I don't have any experience writing word macros. However, I found with a little bit of googling I could create the following

```
Sub CreateHeadings()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With oRng.Find
    .Text = "[0-9]@ Wörter"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Replacement.Style = "Heading 2"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With oRng.Find
    .Text = "([0-9])(l[!a-z])"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1^s\2"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

which almost does what I want. However, I'd need to replace the bolded lines that would appear before my search pattern, so for example something like

> **Some Author; "Title"**

> maybe an additional line

> 565 Wörter

would have to be replaced with the same text, but where the bolded part is formatted to be a heading.

Is there an easy way to do that? Or should I just read up on vba first to fully understand what I'm doing here?

Update: I cleaned up unneeded parts and tried to incorporate helpful advice from Timothy Rylatt.

```
Sub CreateHeadings()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    
    With oRng.Find
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Format = True
    
        With oRng.Find
          .Text = "[0-9]@ Wörter"
        End With
         
      .Replacement.Style = "Heading 2"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
          
          
    End With

End Sub
```

This doesn't do anything right now. I hope I'll understand some of the vba syntax soon so I can update this post with working code for others who might be interested in something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You're already pretty much there so I'm not going to give a full answer.

As you've already figured out how to use wildcards and replace with a specific style all you need is how to find bold text.

```
With oRng.Find
  .Font.Bold = True
  .Format = True
```

Comment: I seem to fail at making a nestled find that would find the pattern as outlined in my example. Do you happen to know if one can specify bold fonts in the .Text parameter, soemthing like .Text = "(bold)* ([0-9]@ Wörter)" and then I could replace the first part via \1.

Comment: @JosephDoob - bold text can only be found using the parameters in my answer. You need to do a separate search for the bold text, so you need to add the pattern for that text and the replacement actions you want to take.